# Adding same table on every click on button

Tags: c#, itext

I have program that should make pdf files with FileSavedialog when the Button1 is clicked.

That works fine.. 
I have also one table, and that table should be added in document.

The problem is that I am updating that table every time(adding rows) before I click on Button1.

When the document is created and saved, I remove all rows from table.

It always add the first table, before first click on Button1, instead of adding table with additional rows:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Dialog.ShowDialog();
        FileStream fr = new FileStream(Dialog.FileName+".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        Document doc = new Document(rec, 40, 40, 30, 30);


        PdfWriter pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fr);

        pdfwriter.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");           

            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(table);              
            doc.Close();
            fr.Close();
}
```

Here is the code for Button2_Click

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
//declaring cells and row|
//getting values 
table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

I hope you understood me.

Update::
When i create multiple files, for example 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf..
1.pdf acts normally,  2.pdf has the rows from 1.pdf and 3.pdf has rows that 2.pdf should have..

Here is the code of Button2_Click()

```
table3.WidthPercentage = 100;
        PdfPCell RedBr1 = new PdfPCell();
        RedBr1.AddElement(new Paragraph(brFakture.ToString()));

        brFakture++;

        try
        {

            PdfPCell Naziv1 = new PdfPCell();
            Naziv1.AddElement(new Paragraph(NazivTb.Text));


            //kolicina
            PdfPCell Kol1 = new PdfPCell();
            double kolicina = Convert.ToDouble(KolTb.Text);
            Kol1.AddElement(new Paragraph(kolicina.ToString("F")));

            //jedinica mere
            PdfPCell Jm1 = new PdfPCell();
            Jm1.AddElement(new Paragraph(JmTb.Text));


            //cena po jedinici
            PdfPCell cenaPoJedinici1 = new PdfPCell();
            double cena = Convert.ToDouble(CenaTb.Text);
            cenaPoJedinici1.AddElement(new Paragraph(cena.ToString("F")));



            double naknada = cena * kolicina;
            PdfPCell UkupnaNaknada1 = new PdfPCell();
            UkupnaNaknada1.AddElement(new Paragraph(naknada.ToString("F")));
            SVE_UKUPNO += naknada;


            table3.SetWidths(new float[6] { 10, 35, 7, 7, 18, 18 });

            PdfPCell[] nizCelija1 = new PdfPCell[6] { RedBr1, Naziv1, Kol1, Jm1, cenaPoJedinici1, UkupnaNaknada1 };

            PdfPRow pocetakTabele1 = new PdfPRow(nizCelija1);
            table3.Rows.Add(pocetakTabele1);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uneti podatak nije broj!");

        }
```

Comment: ,As i  understand your question what if in  **Button2_Click** event  if can you put    Button1.PerformClick();

Comment: The issue is not in the code posted.  Most likely you are calling the constructor for the table [new table()] which is creating a new empty table.

Comment: As @jdweng says, your problem is at best marginally related to the posted code. Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue. One guess: Are the rows you add in `Button2_Click` complete, i.e. as many cells as the table has columns? iText usually does not draw incomplete rows...